# allowEdit property is not working for iOS camera in cordova application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, ios-camera

I am trying to add camera for iOS in cordova application. I have added the plugin cordova-plugin-camera with latest version 4.0.3 and it is working fine but allowEdit property to crop the photo is only working for photo library not for camera.

Here is my code:

```
     navigator.camera.getPicture(
             onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail,
             {
                quality: 100,
                allowEdit:true,
                destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,
                correctOrientation: true,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
              });
     navigator.camera.cleanup(onSuccess, onFail);
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with it.

Comment: The allowEdit property has quirks on almost all platforms (Android, Amazon Fire OS, BlackBerry 10, Firefox OS, WP 7+8). Maybe something changed in iOS and it no longer works there, either.

Comment: @chris Neve, It is working for photo library but not for camera picture.

Comment: The documentation discourages the use of DATA_URL, have you tried using FILE_URI instead? Shouldn't be an issue, but still, worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I have tried FILE_URI and it gave the same issue.